# How to assign local files with git remote?

Tags: git, github

My boss created an empty project on github.
Meanwhile I was developing the app on my local machine without git.
How can I now "assign" my local app with the project created on remote? (github)

I could pull the project from github in a different directory, copy my files into this directory and do a commit / push. But is there a better way without creating a new dir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the github-repository as a remote in your repository then you can push your work to github:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git #setUp github as remote
git push origin # push your changes to github
```

If your work is not in a repository right now just init a new one and commit the changes

```
git init #in project folder
git commit -m 'initial commit'
#setUp remote with above code
#git push origin
```

**Please note**

Just adding the remote repo may not set `master` as an upstream-brunch so you may have to use:

```
git push origin master
```

If you do not want to always have to use the branch name for pushing you can set your branches as upstream-branches with

```
git branch --set-upstream my_branch origin/my_branch
```

Afterwards `git push origin` will work for all branches with an upstream

Comment: Was just finishing my edit to mention it. And master is always created on the first commit

Comment: Classic race condition :)

Comment: I prefer to push with branch names so I always forget about setting master as upstream ;)